# Is the output buffer flushed automatically?

Tags: php

Should I flush the buffer after calling `ob_start()` or will it be flushed automatically? If I'm not calling `ob_flush()` does it affect the website performance.

Comment: you r suppose to use ob_end_flush(); instead of ob_flush();

Comment: ok that's mean i should put ob_start() on the page header and ob_end_flush() in page footer,am i right?

Comment: It is flushed at the end of script execution if you forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is flushed automatically, you can test it with a simple script like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Hello";
?>
```

The performances are the same, since it's flushed automatically.

Comment: The [manual](http://php.net/ob_start) states `Output buffers are stackable [...] Just make sure that you call ob_end_flush() the appropriate number of times.` This seems to indicate that one should call `ob_end_flush()`. I am still searching for a clear-cut reference of the behavior.

Comment: Yes this is in case you call it more than one time in the same page , but if you call it one time in the same page i think it will be flushed automatically.

Comment: @user1391482 It also works with multiple `ob_start()` calls: http://3v4l.org/bnLKG or https://eval.in/127098 (at least with the PHP settings of those sites).